# Context processor for filter empty categories

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

In my blog the posts are divided based on the categories. I've excluded the category named Uncategorized from the list of categories and now I want exclude the categories that are empty.

Into a context_processor I've the query below that working fine:

`MyCategory.objects.exclude(category_name="Uncategorized")`

I've tried with a query like this:

```
def myblog_menu(request):

    myblog_menu_link = MyCategory.objects.exclude(category_name="Uncategorized").filter(category_name__category_set__isnull=True)
    return {
        'myblog_menu_link': myblog_menu_link,
    }
```

but I see this error:

> Unsupported lookup 'category_set' for CharField or join on the field
>   not permitted.

How I can fix it?

**models.py**

```
class MyCategory(models.Mode):
  category_name = models.CharField(...)
  .
  .
  :

class BlogPost(models.Mode):
  title = models.CharField(...)
  category = models.ForeignKey(MyCategory, related_name="category_set", ....)
  .
  .
  :
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude categories that are empty with:

```
MyCategory.objects.exclude(
    category_name='Uncategorized'
).filter(
    category_set__isnull=False
).distinct()
```

This will thus generate a query that looks like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT mycategory.*
FROM mycategory
INNER JOIN blogpost ON mycategory.id = blogpost.category_id
WHERE NOT (mycategory.category_name = 'Uncategorized')
AND blogpost.id IS NOT NULL
```

We here thus specify that if we make a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` with `BlogPost`, that should be empty. The query here is an `INNER JOIN`, which is an optimization, since if we filter out nullables, then it is clear that we do not have to generate those in the first place.

That being said, I *strongly* advice you to alter the `related_name` of your `category` foreign key to `blogpost_set`, or just leave it as it is. The `related_name` is the name of the object in reverse, a `Category` has no `category_set`, it has a set of `blogposts`:

```
class BlogPost(models.Mode):
  title = models.CharField(...)
  category = models.ForeignKey(MyCategory, related_name='blogpost_set', ....)
```

In that case the query is:

```
MyCategory.objects.exclude(
    category_name='Uncategorized'
).filter(
    blogpost_set__isnull=False
).distinct()
```